# Column name as a variable in DataFramesMeta macros

Tags: julia

I'm using the macros from **DataFramesMeta.jl**, and I'd like to have a column name stored in a variable. Here's my input data:

```
using DataFrames
using DataFramesMeta
using Statistics

df = DataFrame(g = ["a", "a", "b", "b"], x = 1:4)
gdf = groupby(df, :g)

colname = :x
```

If I use `colname` in `@select`, it sort of works, except it returns an array instead of a data frame:

```
julia> @select(df, :x)
4×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ x     │
│     │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │
│ 2   │ 2     │
│ 3   │ 3     │
│ 4   │ 4     │

julia> @select(df, colname)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

If I try to use `colname` in `@where` or `@group_by`, they throw method errors:

```
julia> @where(df, :x .> 2)
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ g      │ x     │
│     │ String │ Int64 │
├─────┼────────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ b      │ 3     │
│ 2   │ b      │ 4     │

julia> @where(df, colname .> 2)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isless(::Int64, ::Symbol)
```

```
julia> @based_on(gdf, xavg = mean(:x))
2×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ g      │ xavg    │
│     │ String │ Float64 │
├─────┼────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ a      │ 1.5     │
│ 2   │ b      │ 3.5     │

julia> @based_on(gdf, xavg = mean(colname))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Symbol)
```

Is there a way to pass a column name as a variable in the **DataFramesMeta.jl** macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@where(df, cols(colname) .> 2)
```

straight from the top of the docs: https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFramesMeta.jl#with.